# Android and sqlce

Tags: android, sql-server-ce

I was wondering if android can work with sql compact edition. As far I know, it only has support with sqlite database.

Thanks

Comment: what is sql compact edition anyway? and why would you use that ? -Edit - oh, the MS stuff. yeah, sure. that'll work

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible since SQL Compact does not support Android platforms.